# Which version of Heimdall to use with S2 or S3?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, samsung-galaxy-s-3, clockworkmod-recovery, recovery-mode, heimdall

I think this is a pretty straight forward question.

I have a Galaxy S2 (i727) and a Galaxy S3 (i747) and I'd like to use Heimdall with both of them, but can't seem to find which version of Heimdall supports them.

Working with the 1.3.1, for example, when I boot my S2 into download mode, zadig.exe does not list the Samsung driver everyone mentions.  Heimdall Frontend says it detects a device when I click Utilties->Detect, but I can't seem to interact with anything on the Flash tab.

I'm trying to flash recoveries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never did find out which version of Heimdall to use with either device, but settled on using ODIN3 v1.85 with my S2 (didn't work with an S3, after all).

If you have the AT&T Skyrocket version of the S2, a great place to start looking is: [[HOWTO] THE ULTIMATE NEWB GUIDE > | INSTALL CWM/TWRP | ROOT | UNROOT |the SKYROCKET](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1773659)